# Quantizing age range column Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a csv that contains an age column.

Example data looks like:

```
[0-10)
[10-20)
[20-30)
```

How can I factorise the data:

```
0
1
2
```

depending on the age found in each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pd.factorize:

```
df['code'] = pd.factorize(df[0])[0]
```

output:

```
         0  code
0   [0-10)     0
1  [10-20)     1
2  [20-30)     2
```

Or use category datatype with cat accessor:

```
df['code2'] = df[0].astype('category').cat.codes
```

Output:

```
         0  code  code2
0   [0-10)     0      0
1  [10-20)     1      1
2  [20-30)     2      2
```